# How to cache the EJB remote interface in EJB 3.1?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, java-ee-6, ejb-3.1

Is there any way to **Cache** the reference to remote EJB at client side?

In EJB 2.x it is achieved by caching the **EJBHome**.

> Do we have any similar feature available in **EJB 3.x** to cache the **EJB Remote Interface** which will provide new instance of EJB (Stateless session bean) every time it is used? (In **EJB 2.x** we get new instance of EJB when we call **create()** method on **EJBHome**)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a new instance of the stateless session bean because they're stateless.  The reference you have in the client is a stateless proxy, so the EJB container will obtain a new (or pooled) instance of the stateless bean for each request, and it will destroy (or return to the pool) the instance when the method completes.  For EJB 3, you can simply cache the result of the lookup.  This is implicitly encouraged by the `@EJB` field injection, which encourages you to store the EJB reference in a simple field.

Comment: Hi, I resume an ancient but useful topic. Is it the cached instance thread safe?

Comment: It's probably best to open a new question. It depends what you mean by "instance", but if you mean the client proxy, then yes, it can be called concurrently from multiple threads (e.g., multiple servlet request requests).  The EJB container will ensure that each call to the proxy uses a separate stateless session bean instance.